# How to use the CakePHP function called generatetreelist?

Tags: cakephp

I am new to CakePHP and this function so please help me as you can.

```
generatetreelist(null, null,'{n}.Category.name', '&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;');
```

this shows categories name and childrens perfect but I want to show my all fields of my categories in my `index.ctp`. For example name(already showing), status.
if you could solve my problem? please do it...
in my view I used:

```
foreach($categories as $key=>$value) {

   echo $value;//it shows just name..

}
```

in my controller:

```
$nCategories = $this->Category->generatetreelist(null, '{n}.Category.id','{n}.Category.name', '&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;');
                    $this->set(compact('nCategories',$this->paginate('Category')));
```

Answer (score 4):

you want to use find('**threaded**'), not generatetree **list** ()

Answer (score 1):

```
$params = array(
        'recursive' => -1,
        'fields' => 'Category.id, Category.name, Category.parent_id',

    );
    $categories  = $this->Category->find('threaded',$params);
    debug($categories);
```